# Energy stored in hard disk

Tags: energy, power, data

What is the type of energy stored in hard disk when data is stored? And Can we use it for electric power production?

Comment: A [hard disk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_disk_drive) doesn't store "energy", it stores *information*.

Comment: I knew it. But data is nothing but 0s and 1s, which is nothing but electrons. So there is a possibility.

Comment: How are 1's and 0's electrons?

Comment: @ACuriousMind what if you think of the hard disk as an Ising model? The Hamiltonian might be interpreted as some sort of magnetic potential energy, which of course is defined up to an arbitrary constant

Comment: @ Kyle Kanos Then, please give me a reference that what they actually are.

Comment: @Phoenix87: Hah, yeah, possibly there's a change in total magnetic potential depending on how the 0's and 1's are distributed. But basically any change of any matter configuration will change some potential, so I wouldn't call such a thing "energy storage" if the intended purpose is not *regaining* this energy at some point.

Comment: So, hard disk stores information as magnetic fields. If so, then the entire 0s and 1s (data) in internet or any network are just magnetic fields?

Comment: @ManojMaximum: On HDDs, the 1's and 0's are orientations of the magnetic field on a ferromagnetic strips. On SSDs, the 1's and 0's are designated by an open or closed gate in the transistor. Neither are electrons. For more, see [this post](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/66914/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A hard disk stored both kinetic and magnetic energy - not enough to keep the lights on, but it's definitely there. Of these, the kinetic energy is much larger.

Some numbers:

A typical "fast" hard disk might be 3.5 inch (89 mm nominal), and spin at up to 10k rpm ($\omega \approx 1000 s^{-1}$). The platter is typically made of aluminum (light, strong, cheap, nonmagnetic) with a magnetic coating (where the magic happens). Assuming 1 mm thick platter (may be an underestimate, but gives order of magnitude) the rotational kinetic energy stored will be

$$E = \frac12 I \omega^2\\
= \frac14 m r^2 \omega^2\\
= \frac14 \rho h \pi r^2 r^2 \omega^2\\
\approx 9 J$$

By comparison, the magnetic energy stored in the ones and zeros is absolutely tiny. The easiest way to see this is to simply look at the thickness of the magnetic layer. In order to achieve an information density of about 150 MB/cm^2, one bit is stored in about 30 grains of material, where each grain has about 8 nm diameter [(source)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patterned_media#cite_note-2). This is only going to work if you keep the layer of magnetic material very thin - and so the total mass of material present is necessarily very small. In fact, if the layer is 100 nm thick (seems appropriate when one bit is stored in 30 grains that are 8 nm across), the volume of magnetic material is about $6\cdot 10^{-10} m^3$. Without doing the detailed math, energy stored in the magnetism will be orders of magnitude smaller than the kinetic energy.

Comment: You can *store* KE?

Comment: By my definition - yes you can. That's what flywheels do all the time. Unfortunately in the case of a disk drive it's a lossy storage mechanism - but with a bit of regenerative braking you get part of it back.